# data.table sum of all colums by group

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, lapply

I have a dataframe consisting of 515 integer columns and 2 643 246 rows, from which I would like to subset an unknown number of columns and aggregate the data to a single column showing the sum, by two group-columns.

To do the first part I've used the selection-function from data.table like this,

```
TestData[,c(Kattegori_Henter("Medicine"), "id", "year"), with = FALSE]
```

Where `Kattegori_Henter` is a function returning the name of the columns I would like to select, from a different dataset. From this selection I then want to do the aggregation.

I have attempted a couple different solutions in data.table to perform this aggregation, without getting a result. Given the intro-data.table vignette I believed the solution would be to add

```
TestData[,c(Kattegori_Henter("Medicine"), "id", "year"), with = FALSE, lapply(.SD,sum, na.rm = 
         TRUE), by = c(id, year)]
```

However, this returns the error `Provide either by= or keyby= but not both`, which I do not understand the meaning of, and without google giving any good results.

I then attempted:

```
TestData[,c(Kattegori_Henter("Medicine"), "id", "year"), with = FALSE, a := sum(1.ncol), by = c(id, year)]
```

Which didn't result in anything at all, other than returning the subset dataframe.

The reasoning behind doing this is that I would like to do use lapply on the `kattegori_henter`function, aggregating the 525 columns into a set of categories.

Thanks in advance for all help!

Edit:

Attempted

```
   TestData[,c(Kattegori_Henter("Medicine"), "id", "year"), with =  
   FALSE][, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = c("id", "year")]
```

As mentioned in the comments. The results was the same as the 2nd code above, returning an unchanged dataframe.

Edit 2:

Removed this from the question, due to a comment on it not producing the wanted results:
", which would be equal to the tidyverse-code:

```
Test2 %>% 
group_by(id, year) %>% 
summarise(a = sum(1:ncol(.), na.rm = TRUE)) "
```

Comment: The data.table syntax is `DT[i,j,by]` and you can extend on this by chaining/piping as`DT[i,j,by][i,j,by]` - you have all of it in one set of square braces, more like `DT[,i, j, j, by]`. I guess you need to have something like `TestData[,c(Kattegori_Henter("Medicine"), "id", "year"), with = FALSE][, lapply(.SD,sum, na.rm=TRUE), by = c(id, year)]` - if that works (I can't test it) then let me know and I'll post it as an answer

Comment: As a demo equivalent with built in data: `DT <- data.table(iris); DT[, .(Petal.Length, Sepal.Length, Species)][, sum(.SD), by=Species]`

Comment: Your `group_by(.) %>% summarize(sum(1:ncol(.)))` code is obscure: since you just care about the number of columns, that is perfectly equivalent to `ncol(.) * (ncol(.)+1) / 2` (summing the first *n* natural numbers). That makes you think that that needs to be done by-group? Further, you don't need anything in the frame to do that, just `n <- length(c(Kattegori_Henter("Medicine"), "id", "year")); n*(n+1)/2` should work too. What am I missing?

Comment: For your case, this should work: `TestData[, sum(.SD), by = .(id, year), .SDcols = colnames(TestData[, Kattegori_Henter("Medicine")])]`

Comment: @rg255 Added an edit regarding your proposal!

Comment: @r2evans The tidyverse-code should use the 1:ncol(.) to select the columns which should be summed, i.e. all columns but the grouping-variables.

Comment: `sum(1:ncol(.))` does nothing for selecting columns, it just adds numbers. Your question reads like you want your `data.table` code to function as that *working dplyr code*, but it sounds like you haven't verified that the dplyr code actually does what you want. Perhaps you mean `summarize(a = sum(cur_data()))` for the dplyr variant?

Comment: The data.table-equivalent of *that* code is `[, .(a = sum(.SD)), by=.(id, year)]`.

Comment: @r2evans The posted solution did work, thank you! Just thought I should mention that it does give the same result as the posted dplyr-code (and, after having counted myself, the *correct* results) which given your comment seems a bit strange. I'll edit it out of the question for any futher readers though.

Comment: I'm glad the solution resolved your question. However ... `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(a = sum(1:ncol(.)))` produces three rows, one for each `cyl`, and the `a` sum for all three rows is `66`. Since `mtcars` has 11 columns, that's the same as `11*(11+1)/2`; in contrast, the naïve `sum(mtcars)` is `13942.2`, so `66` is obviously not right. I don't know how you can get `sum(1:ncol(.))` to produce anything other than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code you're looking for is likely:

```r
TestData[, .(a = sum(.SD)), by = .(id, year), .SDcols = Kattegori_Henter("Medicine")]
```